# sfDoctrineGuardPluggin rehashes the password from fixture after data-dump

Tags: symfony1, sfguard

I have s symfony 1.4 with Doctrine and sfDoctrineGuardPlugin.

I am experiencing a problem with **loading fixtures** for **sfGuardUser** which are made from ***symfony doctrine:data-dump***

The core of the problem is that the **passwords in the fixture file are not encrypted** and they will be encrypted in the process of fixture loading.

In the other hand - when we dump data from the data base, the passwords are already encrypted and if we try to load them again, the value of the **password will be rehashed for the second time**.

Does anybody know how to avoid this situation?

I am using this process to prevent data loss when the model needs to be changed. If anybody knows other solution for this particular problem, I will appreciate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a solution to this in the [old symfony forum](http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/83831/).

In short: create a setEncryptedPassword function in your user model like this:

```
  public function setEncryptedPassword($v)
  {
    if ($v !== null) {
        $v = (string) $v;
    }

    if ($this->password !== $v) {
        parent::_set('password', $v);
    }

    return $this;
  }
```

And in your dump change all `password` occurences to `encrypted_password`.

Comment: Thank you @Maerlyn.
I'll try it!

Is this solution means that it will be always neccessary to replace _passwrod_ with _encrypted_password_ ?

Comment: In the fixtures file that's been dumped, yes.